# AutomationUI function test don't start by Azure Pipelines YAML

Tags: azure-devops, ui-automation, azure-pipelines-yaml, vstesthost

I have to run some AutomationUI functional tests from Azure DevOps Pipelines. The tests use a desktop application in WPF/Winforms. The problem is a process of application start but without UI. I run the test using YAML and tasks: VSTest@2 or PowerShell@2. I found exception in Windows Event Viewer:

> The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> (testhost.exe, PID 13060, Thread 3)
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\EnterpriseTools\QualityTools\TestTypes Key cannot
>   be found!
>
> The message resource is present but the message was not found in the
>   message table.

I reinstalled the service as was suggested on a forum, but it still not work.

When I run the same tests from PowerShell or Command Line there is no problem.

Where could be a problem? Is there any recommended way to run functional test? I suppose the problem is between Azure DevOps Pipelines and VS test runner, because the same test was running successful by Team City or from PowerShell/Command Line

Comment: Hi, which test framework do you use?  Appium with WinAppDriver  or what? And could you share some details about your task error and your build definitions?

Comment: This is solved. A problem was to start desktop app within Azure Pipelines - when agent configuration was changed the problem dissapear.